# Sort array of arrays ( could not find duplicate for THIS instance )

Tags: javascript

I have an array for a `timeline chart` of [Google Charts](https://react-google-charts.com/timeline-chart)

So the array looks like follows

```
let data = [
    ['Outreach ICU Follow-up', '2021-01-25', 2021-02-01],
    ['Hospital Stay'         , '2021-01-01', '2021-03-01'],
    ['ICU Stay'              , '2021-01-02', '2021-01-25'],
    ['Outreach ICU Follow-up', '2021-02-20', '2021-03-01'],
    ['ICU Stay'              , '2021-02-01', '2021-02-20'],
]
```

I lined up the date to see the chronological order. I need to sort this by the first data ( `element 1` )

Cant use this because its for objects I think.

```
let ass = data.sort((x,y)=>y.dlk_assess_order-x.dlk_assess_order);
```

And this one is futile as-well.

```
var data = data.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
```

How does one sort and array like this please?
Is there perhaps a `lodash` function?

Comment: what is `dlk_assess_order`? why not sort by exactly what you said `x[1]` and `y[1]`?

Comment: Perhaps I should have thought of that hey. Yep that worked.

Comment: Go ahead with the answer, I'll mark you up.

Comment: Rather than hoping for a perfect example to copy and paste, spend some time understanding what the code you've already found does, and you'll realise that what you want is a trivial modification. There are also [lots of examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/factedu/5ekcwto1/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question said, you simply sort by the element at position `1`

```js
let data = [
    ['Outreach ICU Follow-up', '2021-01-25', '2021-02-01'],
    ['Hospital Stay'         , '2021-01-01', '2021-03-01'],
    ['ICU Stay'              , '2021-01-02', '2021-01-25'],
    ['Outreach ICU Follow-up', '2021-02-20', '2021-03-01'],
    ['ICU Stay'              , '2021-02-01', '2021-02-20'],
]

const sorted = data.sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1]);
console.log(sorted);
```